# How I can implement bit data type in my table

Tags: mysql

In my table student, there is a column attendance of BIT(1) data type.
But when I do:

```
Insert into student values('False')
```

Mysql is giving error that data is too long but i have found in some article we can enter false and true in it.
Also when I insert 1 or 0 and i try to print data on my screen:

```
Select * from student
```

It give some character like '?' as result. I need help in both of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

'False' is string then  try use the related  bit value

```
 Insert into student values(0)
```

and if you need  a  decoded  string as result

```
 select if(your_bit_column, 'True', 'False')
```

Comment: `Insert into student values(false)` should work too